# Input type range styling and displaying value problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

currently I'm working on React BMI calculator app and I have a problem with **input type range elements**. I had couple of problems before,but I've found help here or on Google. Everything was working just fine until I've changed **min** and **max** values to give more sense to the app.

If **min** is set to 1 and **max** is set to 100 everything works just fine.

[image]

As you can see,numbers are displaying in the bubble above the slider thumb ,and that white background effect on selected part of slider track is working also fine. I'm able to move slider thumbs, white background is working and bubble is always right above slider thumb.

Problem occurs when I've tried to switch those min and max to something more real.

**For example :**

- Height - min:150 , max:220
- Weight - min:50 , max : 250

In this case my whole app break ,and this is the result. I don't understand why,bud that white background effect stops working properly ,slider thumbs are all the way to left and if I try to move them ,bubbles will show above the slider thumb.

[image]

Please ,can anybody help me with this? I'm struggling on this all day. All approaches (how to style input type range / how to change colors of input type range / how to make that bubble above it or even how to make that white background selected effect) I've found here or on Google so there can be some mistakes in the code because I've never tried to style or work with these inputs.

Thanks for every help. Here is link for codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tereshkova-ujk45?file=/src/index.css

Comment: I am new to React but I think I can help you with this, just wanted to make clear that you want that white bar to shift towards the left, when you change the min-max value right?

Comment: to be more specific. If you grab slider thumb and move it all the way to left ,there will be no white .only that color which is similar to background. If you move it all the way to right ,there will be only white bar. All the way to the left means minimum value and all the way to right means maximum value. I think problem is in selectedEffect function which is in Range.js file. It changes that white background according to that input value and I can't figure it out how to make it work with different values ,not only min :1 and max :100 . I'll appreciate every help . Thank you

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was working on it and I tried changing the selectedEffect function, but that just completely removed the white color even on sliding

Comment: I am working on it, do let me know if you get any solution

Comment: As I said in question ,I've found that function here on stackoverflow or on google. I've found few similar questions and this was the answer for it. I was really happy it is actually working until I've tried to change them values. I have no idea if there's some better approach for this :/

Comment: Yeah I got your point, I am very new to React but trying my best to solve it with some modifications in the existing code

Comment: Sure ,thank you for your time ! I'm trying to make this work all day and nothing.. I'm going to try find something different on Google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220451/discussion-between-nikhil-singh-and-pinnci).

Comment: Me too. I've started to learn React about 1 month ago. This is one of my first apps,to better understand how React works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do exactly what is required, by modifying your code.

Here is the code, you need to modify your Range.js file as follows,

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Range(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const range = document.getElementById("range");
    const rangeV = document.getElementById("rangeV");

    const range2 = document.getElementById("range2");
    const rangeV2 = document.getElementById("rangeV2");

    const setValue = () => {
      const newValue = Number(
        ((range.value - range.min) * 100) / (range.max - range.min)
      );
      const newPosition = 10 - newValue * 0.2;

      rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}&nbsp;cm</span>`;
      rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;

      const newValue2 = Number(
        ((range2.value - range2.min) * 100) / (range2.max - range2.min)
      );
      const newPosition2 = 10 - newValue2 * 0.2;
      
      rangeV2.innerHTML = `<span>${range2.value}&nbsp;kg</span>`;
      rangeV2.style.left = `calc(${newValue2}% + (${newPosition2}px))`;
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
    range.addEventListener("input", setValue);
    range2.addEventListener("input", setValue);
    // setting default value of both the inputs
    document.getElementById('range').value = 185;
    document.getElementById('range2').value = 150;
  }, []);

  //Selected value effect
  function selectedEffectHeight(e) {
    const val = (e.target.value - 150)*1.42;
    e.target.style.background =
      "linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #fff " +
      val +
      "%, #f0959a " +
      val +
      "%, #f0959a 100%)";
  }

  function selectedEffectWeight(e) {
    const val = (e.target.value - 50)*0.5;
    e.target.style.background =
      "linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #fff " +
      val +
      "%, #f0959a " +
      val +
      "%, #f0959a 100%)";

  }


  return (
    <div className="range">
      <p className="heading">HEIGHT</p>
      <div className="range-wrap">
        <div className="range-value" id="rangeV">
          <span>{props.Height}&nbsp;cm</span>
        </div>
        <input
          type="range"
          id="range"
          min="150"
          max="220"
          onInput={selectedEffectHeight}
          onChange={props.getHeight}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <p className="heading">WEIGHT</p>
      <div className="range-wrap">
        <div className="range-value" id="rangeV2">
          <span>{props.Weight}&nbsp;kg</span>
        </div>
        <input
          type="range"
          id="range2"
          min="50"
          max="250"
          onInput={selectedEffectWeight}
          onChange={props.getWeight}
        ></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Range;
```